# show long filenames immediately in Mountain Lion when hovering mouse and key press

Tags: macos, finder, filesystem

In Leopard, at the finder, when a file/folder had a long filename (and it truncated it with an ellipsis "…"), I just had to press the option (alt) key and hover the cursor on that file/folder, and it would show a tooltip with the full filename.

In Mountain Lion (10.8.2) I can't do that, and I haven't found a way to get the full filename without selecting the actual file and going to "Get Info".

So, is there a way to get the full filename without selecting the file/folder in Mountain Lion just like it could be done in Leopard (immediately get the full filename tooltip via a keyboard key and hovering the cursor over the file/folder)?

Answer (score 2):

The tooltips are still shown in column view and icon view if you hover an item for about two seconds (no need to hold option). I don't know about list view though.

You can also select an item and press return to enter renaming mode.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but that is not the same as the *immediate* tooltip achieved with the option key (I shoudl have stated it better, I already have), and also it doesn't work in list view. Is there a similar way to the option key?